# Unable to remove new lines from list in python scanner

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple error-based SQLI scanner that simply tacks on some common sqli payloads to the ends of query values in urls. I seem to have this working when providing a single url but I cannot get this to work properly when passing a file of urls. The lists of urls with the payloads come back but I have been unable to figure out how to remove the '\n' at the end of each url in the list so that I can request each url.

```
    import argparse
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    import requests
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse, quote_plus
   
    print('\t SQLiScan')
   
    # arguments
    def getArgs():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Error-based SQLi scan')
        parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='List of target urls')
        parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', help='Target url')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args
   
    # Load file of urls for scan
    def loadFile(file):
        target_urls = []
        with open(args.list, 'r') as f:
            for url in f.readlines():
                url = url.rstrip('\n')
                target_urls.append(url)
            return target_urls
   
    # Append payloads to urls
    def appendPayload(url):
        result = []
        payloads = ["1'",'1"',"[1]","[]=1","1`","1/*'*/","1/*!1111'*/",
                    "1'||'asd'||'","1' or '1'='1","1 or 1=1","'or''='",
                    "'1 or 1='1"]
        parsed = urlparse(url)
        queries = parsed.query.split('&')
        for payload in payloads:
            new_query = "&".join(["{}{}".format(query,payload) for query in queries])
            parsed = parsed._replace(query=new_query)
            result.append(urlunparse(parsed))
            request_url = "\n".join(map(str,result))
            request_url = quote_plus(request_url, safe='\n:/')
        return request_url
   
    if __name__ == '__main__':
   
        args = getArgs()
        url = args.url
        urls = loadFile(args.list)
        appendPayload(url)
```

This returns a list like this:

```
['https://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211%27\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211%22\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D910201403208422421%5B1%5D\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D910201403208422421%5B%5D%3D1\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211%60\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211/%2A%27%2A/\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211/%2A%211111%27%2A/\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211%27%7C%7C%27asd%27%7C%7C%27\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211%27+or+%271%27%3D%271\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D9102014032084224211+or+1%3D1\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D910201403208422421%27or%27%27%3D%27\nhttps://www.example.com/sneakers/products/air-jordan-6-retro-unc-1332b420-74d9-439c-9cb1-2bda1b0c8417%3F_branch_match_id%3D910201403208422421%271+or+1%3D%271']
```

After updating code, I am still having difficulty requesting each url properly:

```
# Load file of urls for scan
def loadFile(file):
    target_urls = []
      with open(args.list, 'r') as f:
         for url in f.readlines():
             url = url.rstrip('\n')
             target_urls.append(url)
         return target_urls

# Append payloads to urls
def appendPayload(url):
    result = []
    payloads = ["1'",'1"',"[1]","[]=1","1`","1/*'*/","1/*!1111'*/",
               "1'||'asd'||'","1' or '1'='1","1 or 1=1","'or''='",
               "'1 or 1='1"]
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    queries = parsed.query.split('&')
        for payload in payloads:
            new_query = "&".join(["{}{}".format(query,payload) for 
                                 query in queries])
            parsed = parsed._replace(query=new_query)
            result.append(urlunparse(parsed))
     # request_url = ",".join(map(str, result))
     # result = [quote_plus(x, safe='\n:/') for x in result] 
                
     print(result)
     return result

 if __name__ == '__main__':

     args = getArgs()
     url = args.url
     urls = loadFile(args.list)
     for url in urls:
         request = requests.get(appendPayload(url))
```

This is returning:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '["http://exampe.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1\'", \'http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1"\', \'http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?[1]\', \'http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?[]=1\', \'http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1`\', "http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1/*\'*/", "http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1/*!1111\'*/", "http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1\'||\'asd\'||\'", "http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1\' or \'1\'=\'1", \'http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?1 or 1=1\', "http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?\'or\'\'=\'", "http://example.com/&esheet=52378722&newsitemid=20210215005043&lan=en-US&anchor=example.com&index=1&md5=3367aa50e8bdfe66b505f114178eb403?\'1 or 1=\'1"]'
```

Seems like it may have to do with some of the '' appearing in front of the https: in some of the lines

#### Update:

After much trying, I finally got this working the way I was looking for.

```
import argparse
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import sys
import time
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse, quote_plus
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

# Suppress only the single warning from urllib3 needed.
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)

print('\t SQLiScan')

# arguments
def getArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Error-based SQLi scan')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='List of target urls')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', help='Target url')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

# Load file of urls for scan
def loadFile(file):
    target_urls = []
    with open(args.list, 'r') as f:
        for url in f.readlines():
            url = url.rstrip('\n')
            target_urls.append(url)
        return target_urls

# Append payloads to urls
def appendPayload(data):
    targets = []
    encoded = []
    payloads = ["1'",'1"',"[1]","[]=1","1`","1/*'*/","1/*!1111'*/",
                "1'||'asd'||'","1' or '1'='1","1 or 1=1","'or''='",
                "'1 or 1='1"]
    for url in data:
        parsed_url = urlparse(url)
        url_queries = parsed_url.query.split("&")
        for payload in payloads:
            new_query = "&".join([ "{}{}".format(query, payload) for query in url_queries])
            parsed = parsed_url._replace(query=new_query)
            targets.append(urlunparse(parsed))
    for target in targets:
        encode = quote_plus(target, safe='\n:/')
        encoded.append(encode)
    return encoded

args = getArgs()
data = loadFile(args.list)
targets = appendPayload(data)
counter = 0
for target in targets:
    counter += 1
    print(f'\r{counter} Requests sent', end='', flush=True)
    r = requests.get(target, verify=False)
    if r.status_code == 500 or r.status_code == 302:
        print(r.status_code, + " ", + target)
```

Comment: You remove the newline correctly with `url.rstrip('\n')`. But then you put them back when you do `"\n".join()`

Comment: Also, the code that sets `request_url` should be after the loop, not inside.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to correct this and it is working properly now!

Comment: I can't see how you're getting that list as a result. `return request_url` returns a string, not a list.

Comment: I think you should just return `result`, not `request_url`.